# How to create a flat head screwdriver?

Tags: modeling

[image: The head portion specifically]

So I'm a beginner at blender, and I'm having a hell of a time trying to create the flat head portion. I have one created, but it's a broken mesh. I can't insert loop cuts and all that business when trying to flesh out the details. Anyone have any tips or methods to do this correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to use Subdivision Surface modifier with it?

Comment: Correct, I do. Since it's not a hard edge.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Add Circle (Press <kbd>F6</kbd> and set the vertices 6)

[image]

In the Edit Mode Press <kbd>F</kbd> key to fill the faces and extruded with the <kbd>E</kbd> key.

[image]

Now Add Plane and rotate little to get some shape and angle of the pointer of the screwdriver

[image]

In Edit mode of plane extrude the plane with the <kbd>E</kbd> key to some thickness to plane.

[image]

Now in Edit mode of the plane. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> Duplicate the plane in X axis and move forward and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to mirror the plane. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to flip normals.

Come out of the Edit Mode Select the Plane and <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the Extrude circle and Press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type align object and press <kbd>F6</kbd> and select x axis

[image]

Come out from Edit mode of Plane and select the extruded circle. Add Boolean Modifier. Select the **Operation to Difference** and object to plane. Apply the Modifier and delete the plane. Now you can get the shape of the pointer of screwdriver.

[image]